# How to setup git on my server, and push from itself?

Tags: git

My boss asked me to install git and create a repo on the company server, to keep it all in house and not in third party companies. But damn, this request is too much to me...

The problem is: I have limited access to the server, already have a project running and need to push from another folder in it. It means that I only have access to `public_html` (but the path to this folder is known), which have other 2 folders. One is the current LIVE version, and the other is the development version.

I can create more folders and edit everything inside them, but cannot `cd` to an upper directory or any other folder, besides those two, that it wasn't me who created).

Since we have a web editor, we edit everything in the server and any save we do, already goes to it. Thus, we don't use local files or anything like that.

I have only used GitHub to store commits and versions so I'm a bit lost when it comes to git itself. All the tutorials and explanations I have read says to use `/tmp` or `/var` folders and/or create and remove users, which isn't in my reach.

What I need to do is: knowing all of this restrictions, how do I setup the environment to commit and push from folder A of the server to folder B (supposing that B is the master and A a clone)?

Comment: If your server is reachable by ssh, simply install git on the server as well, create a folder for a repo, call `git init .`, go to your client, clone via the ssh interface, done..

Comment: are you connecting to your server by FTP or SSH ? Do you know how to do a SSH Connection ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this many times for testing purposes.

Go to folder B and make a:
`git init --bare`

This will create multiple files for git purpose. This is now your main repository.

Go to folder A and make a:

`git init`

`git remote add origin PATH/TO/FOLDER/B`

and thats all.

Now you can do: `git add .`, `git commit -m 'messsage'`, `git push/pull origin master` from folder A.

Your folder B will receive all pushes. You can test it making a `git log` in folder B

Comment: Thank you so much! Exactly what I needed!